# How to access JDK tools.jar javac from application deployed in JBoss 7 or WildFly

Tags: java, wildfly, jboss7.x, noclassdeffounderror, jboss-modules

I am deploying an application that tries to use `javac` and finally fails with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main`

How should I make `javac` from `tools.jar` available to the application deployed in JBoss 7 or WildFly ?

Comment: The same question applies for other tools such keytool, javadoc, javah, jstack, jps, etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the process I followed to create a JBoss module for `javac`:

```
mkdir -p modules/com/sun/tools/javac/main
ln -s /usr/java/latest/lib/tools.jar modules/com/sun/tools/javac/main/tools.jar
```

Create `modules/com/sun/tools/javac/main/module.xml` with content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.sun.tools.javac">
    <resources>
        <resource-root path="tools.jar"/>
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <system export="true">
            <paths>
                <path name="com/sun/tools/javac"/>
            </paths>
        </system>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Note: I used a symbolic link because absolute path seems not supported by `resource-root` `path` attribute.

Then either add `Dependencies: com.sun.tools.javac` in `META-INF/MANIFEST.MF` or create a `jboss-deployment-structure.xml` file to declare use of this new module by the application: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform/6.2/html/Development_Guide/Add_an_Explicit_Module_Dependency_to_a_Deployment1.html