# error while connecting the dyn/admin in atg

Tags: java, atg

,531 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/dyn/admin].[AdminProxyServlet]] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-2) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet AdminProxyServlet threw exception: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/tools/javac/Main
at atg.servlet.pagecompile.SunJavaSourceCompiler.javaToClass(SunJavaSourceCompiler.java:110) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pagecompile.jsp11.JSPPageProcessor.javaToClass(JSPPageProcessor.java:405) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pagecompile.PageProcessor.compilePageClass(PageProcessor.java:2437) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pagecompile.PageProcessor.getPageInfo(PageProcessor.java:1787) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pagecompile.jsp12.Jsp12PageProcessor.getPageInfo(Jsp12PageProcessor.java:324) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.minimal.MinimalServletContainer.compileServlet(MinimalServletContainer.java:153) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pagecompile.PageCompileServlet.service(PageCompileServlet.java:306) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.DynamoServlet.service(DynamoServlet.java:152) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:160) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.droplet.DropletEventServlet.service(DropletEventServlet.java:696) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:267) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.service(DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.java:253) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.MimeTyperPipelineServlet.service(MimeTyperPipelineServlet.java:228) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.FileFinderPipelineServlet.service(FileFinderPipelineServlet.java:729) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.service(DispatcherPipelineServletImpl.java:275) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.ServletPathPipelineServlet.service(ServletPathPipelineServlet.java:208) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.security.ExpiredPasswordAdminServlet.service(ExpiredPasswordAdminServlet.java:312) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.BasicAuthenticationPipelineServlet.service(BasicAuthenticationPipelineServlet.java:555) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.DynamoPipelineServlet.service(DynamoPipelineServlet.java:491) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.dtm.TransactionPipelineServlet.service(TransactionPipelineServlet.java:249) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.SecurityServlet.service(SecurityServlet.java:200) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.passRequest(PipelineableServletImpl.java:157) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.passRequest(HeadPipelineServlet.java:1281) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.HeadPipelineServlet.service(HeadPipelineServlet.java:950) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.servlet.pipeline.PipelineableServletImpl.service(PipelineableServletImpl.java:272) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at atg.nucleus.servlet.NucleusProxyServlet.service(NucleusProxyServlet.java:238) [_DAS_slib_sclasses.jar:]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]

Comment: please help me regarding this issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a problem with the default compiler you are using for compiling the JHTML pages (and it is documented on the Oracle Support site [here](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocumentDisplay?id=1943579.1)

The solution is to add the following line

```
javaCompilerClassName=atg.servlet.pagecompile.SunJavaSourceCompiler
```

to either (or both) of the following files in your localconfig folder

```
/atg/dynamo/servlet/pagecompile/ExtendedJhtmlPageProcessor.properties
/atg/dynamo/servlet/pagecompile/PageProcessor.properties
```

You will also need to confirm that the JDK's tools.jar library is available on the CLASSPATH. A suggested solution for JBOSS 7 is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24866883/how-to-access-jdk-tools-jar-javac-from-application-deployed-in-jboss-7).

Answer (score 0):

i am using the two server web logic and jboss for the same local config path
    one is project specification and another one for example respectively so 
    the /atg/dynamo/servlet/pagecompile/ExtendedJhtmlPageProcessor.properties 
    are working for web logic server properly. and for jboss just i delete the configuration of 
    ExtendedJhtmlPageProcessor.properties file and provided the class path setting till the tools.jar 
    now its working properly.

```
thank you for suggestions
```